# SD Card formatting

Tags: adb, internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, formatting

Bought a 128G card I meant to use as mixed internal / portable (or 100% if not possible with mixed) on a

- Galaxy-Xcover-4 (SMG390F)
- Android version 9
- Kernel 3.18.91
- Not rooted (Though I could do it I guess, if there's any method and it is the only way to reach the goal).

First I tried to see if it was possible to do from Phone, but did not find any.

Then I did:

```
adb shell
sm set-force-adoptable true
sm partition disk:179,32 mixed 34
sm set-force-adoptable false
```

It got partitioned, but did not increase internal memory + using the elipsis on SD card view (Settings -> Device Care -> Storage -> SD Card) only crashed. Tried to reboot. But to no avail.

Then I deleted the partitions and re-inserted the card. It asked about formatting the card, and I did; but it is all portable. (I.e. System / Internal is not increased.)

Then I tried same `adb` session as above but with `sm partition disk:179,32 private` (I.e. use 100% of SD-card as internal). This also formatted SD-Card, but now it is not recognized at all.

Re-booted, but still the same.

Is there a way forth to make it increase internal storage?

The phone only have 15G natively and I am constantly pushing close to 100% usage.

Comment: If its becoming complicated I think you should mount bind somefolders in internal storage to folders in external storage and move the files to the respective folders or simply sysmlink them.

Comment: @Silent: One can do that on un-rooted device? Problem is apps. I have all media (including photos) on SD.

Comment: Could you mention the Android version and the encryption status? According to [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_xcover_4-8577.php), looks like Samsung Galaxy Xcover 4 starts with Android 7.0 and is upgradable to Android 9.0. There's [a warning on Android Developers](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable) that on devices encrypted with FBE on Android 7.0-8.1, external SD cannot be used as adoptable storage. Only since Android 9.0 that adoptable storage can be used with FBE.

Comment: @user3342816 actually it needs root sorry.

Comment: @AndrewT. It say "Android version 9" under Software information. (It does not say 9.0 though, but guess it is).

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/adoptable-storage-samsung-android-pie